# Serialize and Deserialize list of object, without break encapsulation

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class called Member that I want to save and load in a XML file.

Here is my methods to load/save

```
    public T LoadGenericDataType<T>(string filename)
    {         

        XmlSerializer xms = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(this._rootFolder + filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        try
        {
            Object v = xms.Deserialize(fileStream);

            fileStream.Close();

            return (T) v;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            fileStream.Close();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public bool SaveGenericDataType<T>(T data, string filename)
    {
        XmlSerializer xms = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(this._rootFolder + filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        try
        {
            xms.Serialize(fileStream, data);
            fileStream.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            fileStream.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In my member class I save a property called Boats, and I don't want to send the original List to any other class so I do a copy of it.

```
    public List<Boat> Boats
    {        
        get => _boats; // this will break encapsulation, but will make it easier to serialize( bad design my me :/ )
        set => _boats = value;
    }

    public List<Boat> Boats1
    {
        get
        {
            List<Boat> copyOfBoats = new List<Boat>(); // this will cause LOADING to fail not saving. 
            foreach (Boat boat in _boats)
            {
                copyOfBoats.Add(boat);
            }

            return copyOfBoats;
        }
        set => _boats = value;
    }
```

What am I missing?  If I try to load an xml with the "Boats1" Property it will fail.

Comment: Why does it fail? Is there some exception? Something else? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I managed to fixed the problem by this.

```
        public List<Boat> Boats
    {
        get
        {
            if (_boats.Count == 0)
                return _boats;

            List<Boat> copyOfBoats = new List<Boat>(); . 
            foreach (Boat boat in _boats)
            {
                copyOfBoats.Add(boat);
            }

            return copyOfBoats;
        }
        set => _boats = value;
    }
```

But it will still break encapsulation if the member don't have any boats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
public List<Boat> Boats1
{
    get
    {
        List<Boat> copyOfBoats = new List<Boat>(); 

        if (_boats.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Boat boat in _boats)
            {
                copyOfBoats.Add(boat);
            }
        }

        return copyOfBoats;
    }
    set => _boats = value;
}
```

That should keep it from returning the orginal list of boats.